# Linking a shared library from a different place than its intended final location

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Suppose I have a `main.lo` which I'd like to link against library  `foo.so`. The linker should always look for `foo.so` at `/foo/bar/lib.so` (fixed path, no search), but I only have `lib.so` in my home directory and not in `/foo/bar/`, which is a protected directory I can't write to myself.

Is it possible to link the lib like this?

**Edit**:
Below is a simple example using `/tmp` instead of `/foo/bar`. Can you make it work by modifying the build script?

**main.c**

```
void foo();
int main(){
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

**foo.c** (multiple-file libraries are overrated)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(){
  puts("foo");
}
```

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
gcc -c -fPIC main.c -o main.lo
gcc -c -fPIC foo.c -o foo.lo
gcc -shared -o foo.so foo.lo

gcc -o pwd main.lo "$PWD/foo.so"
rm -f /tmp/foo.so

#? Link into dest, against /tmp/foo.so but use "$PWD/foo.so"


cp -a foo.so /tmp/foo.so

echo pwd:
./pwd   #this works
echo dest:
./dest
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh That way the specified rpath will be encoded in the binary and later, in production the binary will look for the library at the same place.

Comment: I think I misread the question. Comment removed.

Comment: "link path" and "run path" are different; The earlier is specified `-L/somewhere` and the latter `-Wl,rpath,/somwhere`

Answer (score 3):

You need *two* options to make it work:

First you need to use the `-L` option to tell the linker where the library is actually located at the moment.

Then you need to use the `-rpath` *linker* option to tell where the final location will be. Unfortunately this is a [linker-specific option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) which means you need to use the `-Wl` option to the GCC frontend program.

So the command should look something like

```
$ gcc object.o files.o -o target \
    -L/current/path/to/library -Wl,-rpath,/final/path/to/library -llibrary
```

Note that the two paths can of course be the same.

Comment: This is close but, IMHO, not quite it, as it still does search and relies on the name of the library starting with lib. I'd rather just hardcode an arbitrary path to a *.so file.